# PHP Methods that are always called

Tags: php, oop, methods, call

I'm currently working on an own PHP-MVC-Framework (for experience purposes only).

My question: Is it possible to call a defined function or method, every time a class-method
has been called?

For example:

```
public function view($id) {
     //Code ...
     $this->view->render(__FUNCTION__);
}
```

What I want is:

```
public function view($id) {
    //Code ...
    //render-method is called automatically with functionname as parameter
}
```

I tried different methods ... but without success.
Would be great if someone could help me out with this.

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: +1 for writing "for experience purposes only" just so we can avoid reading all those "don't reinvent the wheel" responses.

Comment: As an aside, your base/front controller class should be calling the render method.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Magic Methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) do achieve this behavior:

```
public function __call($func, $args) {
  if(!method_exists($this, $func)) {
    return;
  }

  // do some coding here
  call_user_func_array($func,$args);
  // do some coding there
}

private function view($arg1, $arg2) {
  // and here
}
```

Remember: view function must be private/protected.

```
$obj->view("asdasd", "asdsad");
```

Should do ::__call(), then ::view() method

Comment: The magic function `__call` is just called if a specific function is not defined. In the above example, if you call `view` `__call` isn't called. But if you call `view1`. And if the function is `private` you've got the error `Fatal error: Call to private method...`, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function as a liaison using PHP's ability to use variable values for execution purposes. for example:

```
function call($func,$param)
{
    $this->$func($param);
    $this->render($func);
}

$myObj->call('view',$id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wrapper method. Call this method and pass everything else as a parameters.